# In Octave, how to load variable and value from txt file ?

Tags: octave

First of all, thanks for helping me. 
My question, lets say I have readme.txt file, and inside looks like below

```
a1 3
b2 4
c3 -2.3
d23 55.6
```

Now, how can I make a function to load this txt file, so that in the Octave, I will **directly** have

```
a1=3
b2=4
c3=-2.3
d23=55.6
```

Allow me say this again, DIRECTLY.  Once I use this function "readFunction("readme.txt")",  all those variables will be load, and ready to use.

I tried [name, num] = textread ("readme.txt", "%s %f"), "num" is the numbers, but I don't know how to convert the cell "name" to variable name. e.g it's wrong if I do char(name(1)) = b(1).   (trying to do a1 = 3).

Or maybe my way is just completely wrong?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Which program creates readme.txt?

Answer (score 1):

First, the idea:

1. Read line by line the file
2. Replace the space with and `=` symbol
3. Optionally add a `;` symbol at the end of each line
4. `eval` the string.

Second, a simple code example:

```
filename="file.txt";
fid=fopen(filename);

line=fgetl(fid);

while line != -1
    eval(strrep(line, ' ', '='));
    line=fgetl(fid);  
endwhile

fclose(fid);
```